# Calculating the distance between a set of UTM coordinates

Tags: gps, distance, utm

I would like to calculate the distance between several GPS points, these data are projected into UTM Zone 30.

I am using Postgresql 9.3 but I am happy to see results with any software or website such as Microsoft Excel.

PS: This data is from Madrid (Spain)

Eg:

> 442778 (x) 4475112 (y)

```
 442767(X)     4475268(y)
```

Comment: What is the coordinate system you have used? Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) is not a single map projection but rather a projection sitting on top of a geographic coordinate system. Is the underlying coordinate system European Datum 1950? WGS1984? etc...

Comment: I would suggest the proximity tools in ArcGIS but they are geared to an ArcAdvanced licence http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000048000000 you can also have a look at the XYtoLine tool in ArcGIS http://www.exprodat.com/blogs/blog_Tip-25-Using-the-XY-To-Line-tool.htm

Comment: Hi Spk578 is WGS1984 sorry, for my miss information.

Comment: @spk578 just as an FYI, a spatial join can be used in place of the proximity tools restricted to ArcGIS Advanced in many (but not all) cases. There are a few questions here that suggest this workaround.